# Center all images if smaller than parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

My code works fine if I have enough images: it scrolls and all is good.

However, if the images' combined width is less than the parent div's width it does not scroll (as it is supposed to) but all images are aligned to the left.

How can I make them align to the center?

I am pretty sure that this is an easy one, but I just can't find the solution.

I would appreciate if someone could help please.

Thanks
Kai

It is for this plugin: http://www.smoothdivscroll.com/

My CSS looks like this

```
#makeMeScrollable
    {
        width:100%;
        height: 55px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px 0; 
    }
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img, #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a
{
position: relative;
float: left;
margin: 0 10px;
padding: 0;

filter: url(stylesheets/filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */ 
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */ 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome & Safari 6+ */

/* If you don't want the images in the scroller to be selectable, try the following
    block of code. It's just a nice feature that prevent the images from
    accidentally becoming selected/inverted when the user interacts with the scroller. */
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
#makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea img:hover, #makeMeScrollable div.scrollableArea a:hover
{
filter: none; 
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0); 
}
```

And the html is:

```
<div id = "makeMeScrollable">
            <img src = "images/test.png"
               id = "1" />

            <img src = "images/test2.png"
               id = "2" />
        </div>
```

Comment: you'll need to show your markup. The approach widely varies based on how you've structured your images. @jtheman - that would only work if they're set to `display:block`. And wouldn't work if they're in containing elements that are floated or not block-level... The question really needs to be more specific to give a decent answer.

Comment: If you show us your great code then we can help. You might want to have an surrounding container DIV thats centered but its unclear without the code.

Comment: Tell us what your structure is if you want more help, but css as jtheman suggested, or usign `display: box` or using tables or... it's really hard without knowing more

Answer (score 0):

Try `margin:auto` on your images as this will center block level elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center">
<img src="img.png">
</div>
```